# The relation between convex shape and its minimum bounding box

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, computational-geometry

The minimum bounding box (MBB) is the kind of hull that is the smallest enclosing rectangle/box around a set of points.

The vertices of convex polygon and polyhedron in two and three-dimension are at hand. The dimensions of their rectangle (2D) and cube (3d) MBB are determined. For some reason, I need to MBB center of polygon and polyhedron.

I want to know is there any relation for acquiring the center of MBB based on shape vertices and its dimensions in two and three-dimension.

Any tip that makes a way to know it, makes me happy.

Comment: What center? The center of mass?

Comment: Your question isn't clear for two reasons: a) is the center of a polygon (or a polyhedron in 3D) with respect to its area (volume in the case of 3D) or is it the barycenter of its vertices ?  b) for a (strictly) convex polygon (polyhedron in 3D) there is no difference between it and its convex hull...

Comment: @JeanMarie Center with respect to area and uniform mass distribution.
My impression from your comment is: There is no difference between the center of the convex shape and the center of its convex hull. Is this correct:???

Comment: @JoshuaWang Center with respect to the area/volume and uniform mass distribution

Comment: Yes ; convex hull of P = P for convex polygons P.

Comment: @JeanMarie I draw some 2D shapes with its convex hull (with help of GEOGABRA software). But it seems your comment doesn't work.

Comment: You have said (first sentence) that you begin with a **convex** shape: in this case, the convex hull of the shape is identical to the shape. It may happen that you have begun with a non-convex shape...

Comment: @JeanMarie You right, I added details about the convex hull. I mean rectangle/cube convex hull.

Comment: More explicitly, are you refering to the "minimum bounding box(es)" (in terms of surface or volume) as defined here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms ? It is not the same at all that a convex hull...

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes; I added your illustrative comment to the question.